# Toggle fields to be full in the url for tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Is there a way to force if the fields should be `full` in the api url?

For example, now you select if the field is full by doing:

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    foo = fields.ForeignKey(FooFooResource, 'foo', full=True)
```

Is it possible to overwrite the `full` in the url by doing something like:

```
example.com/api/foo/?foo__full=false
```

or

```
example.com/api/foo/?foo__full=true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the code to make it work:

```
class RelatedResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'user')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Related.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'related'


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    related = fields.ToOneField(RelatedResource, 'related', full=False) # Default is false

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        show_full = bundle.request.GET.get('full', "false").lower() == "true"
        if show_full:
            old_full = self.related.full
            self.related.full = True
            bundle.data['related'] = self.related.dehydrate(bundle)
            self.related.full = old_full
        return bundle
```

I created a gist to make changes: https://gist.github.com/2897326

Comment: I improved upon @santiagobasulto answer and made a dynamic hydrate method for this. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/MRHarrison/c810c27d3c5259a3b4e7

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the [Github](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/389):

> There isn't a built-in way to do this right now. It's possible to do in dehydrate, checking `if bundle.request.GET.get('foo__full', True) == False` then just swapping out the data in `bundle.data`. Takes a little bit of code though.